# How to save my data in a cloud?

Tags: google-drive-api, cloud, server, dropbox

I don't know if this is possible, but I would like to save some data of my website,  like images and documents in a cloud like dropbox or google drive and I want that these data are available and visible to someone looking my site.
is it possible? (My intention is to continue storing the html,js etc data on the server)

Comment: You should look into the storage service within your selected cloud provider. So once you chose your cloud provider you should be using their storage service to save all the data ( other than in a DB ). That should be the most efficient way to do that and each cloud provider should detail this part. Yes, you could use external solutions and as long as they are not critical(you can afford latency or lost of data) to your application(s) then you should probably be just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with Dropbox or Google Drive.

For Dropbox, put your all images to a folder and make this folder public. Then, right click the image or js file and select the `copy public link`. You can use this link for your images or js files.

Comment: Please check this for more specs about my issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/30675159/4842333