# File-upload: how to upload files in an external cloud folder javascript modification

Tags: javascript, file-upload, cloud, dropbox

I have this `.js` in order to upload a file and show a list of the uploaded files. I have 2 problems:

1. How can I show the listed files not in alphabetical but in order of upload?
2. I know it's possible to load these files in a dropbox or drive folder instead of in a folder in the server, how can I do this?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
echo 'succesfully uploaded';
$structure = 'uploadedfiles/';
$target_file = $structure.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
}
$dir    = 'up/';
$files = scandir($dir);
echo '<h1>List of Uploaded Files</h1> <br><hr>';
$i = 1;
foreach ($files as $key) 
{
    if ($i>3) 
    {
    $j = $i-3;
    echo $j."<a href='up/".$key."'>".$key."</a><hr>";
    }
    $i++;

}
echo 'End of Files';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're referring to the list of files shown on your own site, you'll want to maintain the desired order in some persistent list somewhere, or sort them based on whatever criteria you want, before showing the list of files to the user. (E.g., based on the modified time from the filesystem, etc.)
2. To upload files to Dropbox programmatically, you'll need to use the Dropbox API:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core

There's an official PHP SDK here:

- [download](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/php)
- [tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php)
- [documentation](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/)

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to modify the `.js` in order to both order the list and add the dropbox api without too much success, I'm a noob in `.js` coding. Can you give me some help to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the `modified` filter in Dropbox(Web)
2. Right click the file you want to use and selected url.  It is gonna be    something like this:

   https://www.dropbox.com/s/6fk1231mvp9idx7/cos.rar?dl=0

replace `www` with `dl`. It is gonna be something like this:

```
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/6fk1231mvp9idx7/cos.rar?dl=0
```

Comment: And then, what I have to do? I need the `up` folder in the script being a dropbox folder